# list and dictionary: which one is faster

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following pieces of code doing the sorting of a list by swapping pairs of elements:

```
# Complete the minimumSwaps function below.
def minimumSwaps(arr):
    counter = 0
    val_2_indx = {val: arr.index(val) for val in arr}
    for indx, x in enumerate(arr):
        if x != indx+1:
            arr[indx] = indx+1
            s_indx = val_2_indx[indx+1]
            arr[s_indx] = x

            val_2_indx[indx+1] = indx
            val_2_indx[x] = s_indx
            counter += 1
    return counter

def minimumSwaps(arr):
    temp = [0] * (len(arr) + 1)
    for pos, val in enumerate(arr):
        temp[val] = pos
    swaps = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i] != i+1:
            swaps += 1
            t = arr[i]
            arr[i] = i+1
            arr[temp[i+1]] = t
            temp[t] = temp[i+1]
            temp[i+1] = i
    return swaps
```

The second function works much faster than the first one. However, I was told that dictionary is faster than list. 
What's the reason here?

Comment: I think what the person was trying to tell you was that object *lookup* in dictionaries is faster. ie: Finding the value for the key "john" in a dictionary is faster than finding the index of "john" in a list.

Answer (score 3):

A list is a data structure, and a dictionary is a data structure. It doesn't make sense to say one is "faster" than the other, any more than you can say that an apple is faster than an orange. One might grow faster, you might be able to eat the other one faster, and they might both fall to the ground at the same speed when you drop them. It's not the fruit that's faster, it's what you do with it.

If your problem is that you have a sequence of strings and you want to know the position of a given string in the sequence, then consider these options:

- You can store the sequence as a list. Finding the position of a given string using the `.index` method requires a [linear search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search), iterating through the list in O(n) time.
- You can store a dictionary mapping strings to their positions. Finding the position of a given string requires looking it up in the dictionary, in O(1) time.

So it is faster *to solve that problem* using a dictionary.
But note also that in your first function, you are building the dictionary using the list's `.index` method - which means doing n linear searches each in O(n) time, building the dictionary in O(n^2) time **because you are using a list for something lists are slow at**. If you build the dictionary without doing linear searches, then it will take O(n) time instead:

```py
    val_2_indx = { val: i for i, val in enumerate(arr) }
```

But now consider a different problem. You have a sequence of numbers, and they happen to be the numbers from 1 to n in some order. You want to be able to look up the position of a number in the sequence:

- You can store the sequence as a list. Finding the position of a given number requires linear search again, in O(n) time.
- You can store them in a dictionary like before, and do lookups in O(1) time.
- You can store the *inverse sequence* in a list, so that `lst[i]` holds the *position* of the value `i` in the original sequence. This works because every permutation is invertible. Now getting the position of `i` is a simple list access, in O(1) time.

This is a different problem, so it can take a different amount of time to solve. In this case, both the list and the dictionary allow a solution in O(1) time, but it turns out it's more efficient to use a list. Getting by key in a dictionary has a higher constant time than getting by index in a list, because getting by key in a dictionary requires computing a hash, and then probing an array to find the right index. (Getting from a list just requires accessing an array at an already-known index.)

This second problem is the one in your second function. See this part:

```py
    temp = [0] * (len(arr) + 1)
    for pos, val in enumerate(arr):
        temp[val] = pos
```

This creates a list `temp`, where `temp[val] = pos` whenever `arr[pos] == val`. This means the list `temp` is the inverse permutation of `arr`. Later in the code, `temp` is used only to get these positions by index, which is an O(1) operation and happens to be faster than looking up a key in a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for the analogy, which is amazing.
In fact, the second function `minimumSwaps ` is from someone, and I understand that they use a list to map from the value to its index. Therefore, I wrote the 1st `minimumSwaps ` function, but as I said, my function is much slower if the input is  long.
So I think in this case, both dictionary and list have O(1) time, why the list performs better? Can you explain more about `getting by key in a dictionary has a higher constant time than getting by index in a list?`

Comment: I've expanded the answer to explain a bit why getting from a list is more efficient than getting from a dictionary. I've also added a point because I noticed that your dict comprehension in function 1 uses the lists's `.index` method, which means you're using a list for something lists are slow at.